# Take a percentage of your clients online payment profits

Tags: paypal, payment

I'm a freelancer and I'm negotiating with a potential client for a full e-commerce website using PayPal Payment Pro.

They want to list and sell everything from cheap fittings/fixtures to very expensive furniture on there new website.

It's a BIG job, and everything would be designed and developed bespoke. Right now were at the £2,500 mark, but I don't think they're going to agree... However, I had a thought.

They make a great profit just from instore sales. I'd be happy to reduce the design/development price by 50% (to possibly 65%) if they agree to give me 3% to 5% of all online sales.

My question is, how would I do this with PayPal Payment Pro?

I can record all online sales and invoice them for 3% to 5% each month, but I'd rather it be done automatically. I can't find any documentation on how to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is integrating Express Checkout and Pro into the website like usual, and then install [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) on the server to automate payments from the website owner to you.

Within the IPN script you can setup a [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) request that submits the payment from the website owner's account to your account accordingly.  You can calculate your commission from within this based on the order total and push the funds to your account.

IPN occurs in real-time (or at least generally very close to it) so the procedure would be completely automated at that point and you would get your commission payments immediately when each order goes through.